# last record displaying in all rows

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of EventObject(s). Each object has title and city and many others attributes. I want to show title of cell as event title, and subtitle of cell as event city. I tried doing that in the following, but I only get the last object displayed 4 times (that is the number of objects in the array).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
//    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];

    EventObject *eventInstance = [[EventObject alloc] init];
    int row = [indexPath row];

    eventInstance = eventObjectsArray[row];
    cell.textLabel.text = eventInstance.eventTitle;
    NSLog(@"Event Title: %@", eventInstance.eventTitle);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = eventInstance.eventCity;

    return cell;
}
```

What did I do wrong? I am learning objective-c so beginners errors surely. Thanks

EDIT: This is how I am inserting objects:

```
 //get events from database
    eventsDictionary = [eventInstance getEventsObjects];

    //process each key in dictionary and assign to eventInstance
    for(id key in eventsDictionary)
    {
         eventInstance.eventId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key[@"id"]];
         eventInstance.eventTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key[@"title"]];
         eventInstance.eventDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key[@"description"]];
         eventInstance.eventCity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key[@"city"]];
         [eventObjectsArray addObject:eventInstance];
    }
```

Comment: How you are storing objects in eventObjectsArray? Post that code also

Comment: Why would you want to create a new instance of the "EventObject" class.Just create a reference of the class and take the object from your "eventObjectsArray".As @Bhargavi said , show us the code where you insert the objects in the array.

Comment: The problem is definitely not in the code you posted. It must be in how you populate `eventObjectsArray`.

Comment: I added the code for inserting the objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestions**

*[This can be issue]*

While adding objects in your eventObjectsArray make sure to have new insatnce of EventObject everytime before you add object

```
EventObject *eventInstance = [[EventObject alloc] init];
eventInstance.eventTitle = @"your title";
eventInstance.eventCity  = @"your city";
[eventObjectsArray addObject:eventInstance];
```

*[This is suggestion as you should know this to improve your coding standard and memory management]*

While retriving objects back from array you really don't need to have instance of custom object rather have refrence to it like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //EventObject *eventInstance = [[EventObject alloc] init]; //you don't need this
    int row = [indexPath row];

    EventObject *eventInstance = eventObjectsArray[row]; // make reference like this
    cell.textLabel.text = eventInstance.eventTitle;
    NSLog(@"Event Title: %@", eventInstance.eventTitle);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = eventInstance.eventCity;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I tried to copy paste the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath and it didn't work unfortunately. Any other suggestions mate? I really appreciate the detailed answer :)

Comment: Sorry modified a bit and you were right about when inserting I have to create EventObject every time. Thanks alot mate.

Comment: cool.try copying all the code the next time so that its easy for any one to make out whats wrong.